# Remove every nth element from swift array

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there an easy way to remove every nth element from a swift array. For example, in the array below:

```
thisArray = [2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.5, 3.3, 1.2, 3.6, 10.3, 4.4, 2.0, 13.0]
```

If `n = 3` and start count from first element would like to return:

```
returnThis = [2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 4.5, 1.2, 3.6, 4.4, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
// swift 4.1:
thisArray.enumerated().compactMap { index, element in index % 3 == 2 ? nil : element }
```

- Use `.enumerated()` to attach the indices
- Then use `.compactMap` to filter out items at indices 2, 5, 8, ... by returning `nil`, and strip the index for the rest by returning just `element`.

(If you are using Swift 4.0 or below, use `.flatMap` instead of `.compactMap`. The `.compactMap` method was introduced in Swift 4.1 by [SE-0187](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md))

(If you are stuck with Swift 2, use `.enumerate()` instead of `.enumerated()`.)

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer Thanks, changed to `.compactMap()`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Functional style solutions have already been posted I am using here an old fashion way approach

```
let nums = [2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.5, 3.3, 1.2, 3.6, 10.3, 4.4, 2.0, 13.0]

var filteredNums = [Double]()
for elm in nums.enumerate() where elm.index % 3 != 2 {
    filteredNums.append(elm.element)
}
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I find this much easier to read and to construct in my head than all the functional wizardry.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the new array directly from the old
array by adjusting the indices. For `n=3` it looks like this:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...    old array index
    | |   / /   / /
    | |  | |   / /
    | |  | |  / /
    | |  / / / / 
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...        new array index
```

Code:

```
let thisArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let n = 3

let newCount = thisArray.count - thisArray.count/n
let newArray = (0..<newCount).map { thisArray[$0 + $0/(n - 1)] }

print(newArray) // [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

After taking `n-1` elements from the old array 
you have to skip one element. This is achieved by adding `$0/(n - 1)`
to the (new) array index `$0` in the map closure.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using `flatMap` which among other things it removes nils from the array, thus we'll simply return `nil` for the indexes we want to remove:

```
let n = 3
let arr = [2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.5, 3.3, 1.2, 3.6, 10.3, 4.4, 2.0, 13.0]
let filteredArr = arr.enumerate().flatMap {$0.index % n == n - 1 ? nil : $0.element }
```

For swift 3:

```
let filteredArr = thisArray.enumerated().flatMap {$0.offset % n == n - 1 ? nil : $0.element }
```

Generally speaking, you ignore the `N-1`th element of the array.

A more functional solution  can be achieved via strides:

```
let filteredArr = (n-1).stride(to: arr.count, by: n).flatMap { arr[($0-n+1)..<$0] }
```

The approach here is to obtain the indexes that will be filtered out, and then join the slices between two consecutive filtered out indexes.

Or another approach, via `reduce`, which is actually to what filter/map/flatMap reduce to:

```
let filteredArr = arr.enumerate().reduce([]) { $1.0 % n == n - 1 ? $0 : $0 + [$1.1] }
// or, both produce the same results
let filteredArr = arr.reduce((0,[])) { ($0.0 + 1, $0.0 % n == n - 1 ? $0.1 : $0.1 + [$1]) }.1
```

And not lastly, a mathematical approach: take the set of indexes in the array, substract the indexes that we don't want, built the result array from the sorted resulted indexes:

```
let filteredArr = Set(0..<arr.count).subtract((n-1).stride(to: arr.count, by: n)).sort(<).map { arr[$0] }
```