# Filter an array by time interval

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filtering

In my app, I record the acceleration data taken from the device's accelerometer every **20 milliseconds**. I have a class aptly named `AccelerationData` to store these values. I also record the timestamp of each reading in milliseconds.

```
class AccelerationData {
    var timestamp: Int64 = 0 // in milliseconds
    var x: Double = 0.0
    var y: Double = 0.0
    var z: Double = 0.0

    var timestampDate: Date {
        return Date(milliseconds: timestamp)
    }

    var JSONDictionary: [String: Any] {
        let jsonDictionary: [String: Any] = [
            "X": x,
            "Y": y,
            "Z": z,
            "TIME": timestamp
        ]
        return jsonDictionary
    }
}

extension Date {

    var milliseconds: Int64 {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }

    init(milliseconds: Int64) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds / 1000))
    }

}
```

After the recording is over, I need to create a JSON body of all these readings. Instead of taking all these readings, I want to filter it by readings that happened every 500 milliseconds (0.5 seconds).

From research I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39196109/1077789) that you can use `flatMap` for a task like this but I'm not sure how to apply this when there are dynamic values like timestamps are involved.

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to get started on this.

Comment: Note that `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)` takes a time interval in *seconds,* not milliseconds.

Comment: @MartinR Oh yeah! I actually have a separate extension method to do that. I had forgotten to update the property in the class. Updated my code.

Comment: Filter by readings "every 500 millis"? What happens if 2 seconds go by between readings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use  a simple for-loop for that purpose.
Assuming that the data is ordered by timestamp, it could look like this:

```
let measurements: [AccelerationData] = ... // your full array of acceleration data
var reducedMeasurements = [AccelerationData]()

var nextTimeStamp = measurements.first!.timestamp // Assuming that the array is not empty
for accData in measurements {
    if accData.timestamp >= nextTimeStamp {
        reducedMeasurements.append(accData)
        nextTimeStamp += 500 // add 0.5 seconds
    }
}
```

If you "insist" on using a filter, here is a possible solution:

```
func timeFilter(delta: Int64) -> (Int64) -> Bool {
    var nextTimeStamp: Int64?
    return { timeStamp in
        if let next = nextTimeStamp {
            if timeStamp >= next {
                nextTimeStamp = next + delta
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            // First call:
            nextTimeStamp = timeStamp + delta
            return true
        }
    }
}

let measurements: [AccelerationData] = ...
let filter = timeFilter(delta: 500)
let reducedMeasurements = measurements.filter { filter($0.timestamp) }
```

`timeFilter(delta: 500)` creates a closure which uses a captured
variable to keep track of the next timestamp. The code can probably
be simplified, but hopefully demonstrates the idea.

Comment: nextTimeStamp being a date, isn't it `nextTimeStamp += 0.5` ?

Comment: @Guig: OP defined the property as `var timestamp: Int64 = 0 // in milliseconds`

Comment: @MartinR - you need a minor edit in the `timeFilter()` function... the first time `timeStamp >= nextTimeStamp`, nextTimeStamp needs to be updated with `if nextTimeStamp == Int64.min { nextTimeStamp = timeStamp }` ... otherwise, you're just incrementing `Int64.min` by 500 each time through...

Comment: @DonMag: Indeed! That shows again that optionals should be used instead of "magic constants". Hopefully it is correct now!